# SAS - read multiple CSV files and create a dataset for each one of them

Tags: sas

I use this code to input CSV files data into SAS:

```
%macro drive(dir,ext); 
   %local cnt filrf rc did memcnt name; 
   %let cnt=0;          

   %let filrf=mydir;    
   %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(filrf,&dir)); 
   %let did=%sysfunc(dopen(&filrf));
   %if &did ne 0 %then %do;   
     %let memcnt=%sysfunc(dnum(&did));    

     %do i=1 %to &memcnt;              

       %let name=%qscan(%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i)),-1,.);                    

       %if %qupcase(%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i))) ne %qupcase(&name) %then %do;
         %if %superq(&ext) = %superq(&name) %then %do;                         
           %let cnt=%eval(&cnt+1);       
           %put %qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));

           proc import 
             datafile="&dir\%qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i))"
             dbms=csv
             replace
             out=dsn&cnt 
           ;            
           run;         

         %end; 
       %end;      
     %end;
   %end;
   %else
     %put &dir cannot be open.;

   %if &did %then %let rc=%sysfunc(dclose(&did));      

 %mend drive;

%drive(C:path\to\folder\,csv)
```

but it names the datasets as dsn1, dsn2 etc while I want to have the name of the file (without the CSV part) as the dataset name. How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure the filenames will work as dataset names? SAS dataset names are limited to 32 characters and must follow SAS naming rules.

Comment: Does that code even work? You are using `%superq()` function wrong.  It wants the name of the macro variable to quote, not the value to quote.

Comment: @Tom code is originally from here and it does work https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=mcrolref&docsetTarget=n0ctmldxf23ixtn1kqsoh5bsgmg8.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: @Reeza SAS posts a lot of poorly written code because they are just intended to emphasize a point.  If you call that code with `EXT=csv` then the `%superq(&ext)` expression is going to quote the value of the undefined `CSV` macro variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem occur cause of macro call. Change folder to correct one, like :

```
%drive(C:\temp\,csv)
```

UPDATE(solving the problem of naming the datasets):

```
%macro read(dir,ext);%macro d; %mend d;
filename filelist pipe "dir /b &dir*.&ext"; 

data want;
  infile filelist dlm="¬";
  length cmd_line $2000;
  input cmd_line;
run;

proc sql noprint;
   select tranwrd(cmd_line,".&ext",'') into:dataset_list separated by ' ' from want;
quit;

%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&dataset_list));
   %let dataset_name = %scan(&dataset_list,&i,%str( ));
          proc import datafile="&dir.&dataset_name..&ext" out=&dataset_name
           dbms=csv replace;            
          run;
%end;
filename filelist clear;
%mend read;

%read(c:\temp\,csv);
```

Comment: Will not help to overwrite the out=dsn&cnt

Comment: Now better! I had used call execute for the whole thing because it more hassel free. But the question code was way of already.

Comment: Will only work if you have pipe access enabled, which isn't guaranteed. The above program works regardless of those settings.

Answer (score 0):

For the innards you want to deal with the directory member name retrieved with `dread`, instead of dealing with the i'th processed file, as coded by `ds&cnt`.

`FIND` the position of the dot (`.`) in the filename and separate out the name and extension parts.  After extracting the name part of the filename, `compress` out all non SAS name characters.

```
 %do i=1 %to &memcnt;              

   %let filename = %qsysfunc(dread(&did,&i));

   %let pindex = %sysfunc(FIND(&filename,.,-%length(&filename)));

   %if &pindex > 1 %then %do;
     %let extpart = %upcase(%substr(&filename,&pindex));
     %let namepart = %substr(&filename,1, &pindex);

     %* keep only characters that are valid for a sas name (normalize the namepart);
     %let sasname = %sysfunc(compress(&namepart,,kn));

     %if &extpart = CSV %then %do;

       proc import 
         datafile="&dir\&filename"
         dbms=csv
         replace
         out=work.&sasname
       ;            
       run;         

     %end;
   %end;
 %end;
```

If the filenames are too long the generated `IMPORT` will ERROR.  Be sure to coordinate with data providers so you get

- right lengthed filenames, and
- filenames that do not collide when normalized